# Code to generate Crystal Reports report works fine in CLI, but "Data source name not found" when accessed from browser

Tags: php, com, crystal-reports, command, report

I'm trying to generate a report from PHP, using Crystal Reports,
The code seems to be correct:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
die('Please specify an ID');
}

$path = "c:\\wamp\\www\\billing\\reports";
$file = $chemin."\\bill_".$id.".pdf";
$app_obj = new COM("CrystalRuntime.Application") or Die ("Did not open");
$report= $path."\\bill.rpt";

$rpt_obj= $app_obj->OpenReport($report,1);
$app_obj->LogOnServer("p2ssql.dll","host","bdd","userbd","passwordbd");
$rpt_obj->EnableParameterPrompting = FALSE;
$rpt_obj->RecordSelectionFormula = "{F_DOCLIGNE.DO_Piece}='$id'";

$rpt_obj->ExportOptions->DiskFileName =  $file;
$rpt_obj->ExportOptions->PDFExportAllPages = true;
$rpt_obj->ExportOptions->DestinationType = 1;
$rpt_obj->ExportOptions->FormatType = 31; 
$rpt_obj->Export(false);

header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
readfile($file);
?>
```

If I run the script from command line, it works just fine, and I have the PDF exported and parsed in the console.

But from a browser's point of view, the story is different,
If you get the request through Apache, I get this exception :

```
com_exception: Source: Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer
Details : IM002:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified in C:\wamp\www\facture\report.php on line 25
```

On the report, the database connection is made through ODBC, I couldn't use that, as any other driver, marked with ODBC refused to work.

---

Comment: You're using `$_GET['id']` dangerously, without validating: e.g., if I input `\\..\\..\\..\\foo` I can get out of the web root.

Comment: This is for development purposes only, when it will work I'll add all the conditions to make sure nothing slips the wrong way. but thank you !

Comment: Crystal Reports is a creature of the devil. Stay away from it :)

Comment: What a good alternative would be to natively generate reports from PHP ? Thanks in advance

Comment: is the 'script from command line' on the same machine as web server (Apache)?

Comment: Well, I agree with @Morgar, however, if you want to generate PDF documents, use PHP's PDF class. http://uk2.php.net/pdf - However, if you've got money to spend, go and buy ColdFusion, install the WDDX module and output PDF documents with just HTML.

Comment: @Craig Yes, the Web server is on the same machine from which I'm accessing the pages from the browser.

Comment: @Richard D. I have an rpt file, provided by the company I work for, thanks anyway. Perhaps, I'll have a look at your solution and rebuild the output.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to set some environmental variables. Below is what I had to set to use a different ODBC driver (note: on OS X).

```
<?php
    putenv("ODBCINSTINI=/path/to/odbcinst.ini");
    putenv("ODBCINI=/path/to/odbc.ini");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using Wamp. This behaviour is very probably related to the user that the web server (Apache) runs under.

When you run PHP from CLI, PHP.exe inherits your user profile (in terms of database/network/filesystem access rights); on the other hand, usually Apache (and IIS,too) runs under different, unprivileged credentials, to prevent hackers from damaging and exploiting the server.

In Apache, you can change this behaviour modifying the `httpd.conf` Apache config file (in your case it could be located under `C:\wamp\apache\conf`), changing the `User` and/or `Group` config directives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paolo,
I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: @Logicbloke it can be due to the php.ini ODBC default connection settings.